# Laptop battery capacity going up 3% after each cycle

Tags: laptop, battery

I know that it is normal for capacity of a laptop battery to decrease over time, but mine is actually only going up after each cycle. I don't expect much from my Chinese laptop called Chuwi Lapbook pro, but maybe there is a way to reset those numbers / recalibrate battery, or just delete battery usage history?

Battery type: Li-po 5000mah 7.8v. Power abruptly cuts off at around 25-28% remaining charge.

Using Ubuntu and TLP:

```
--- TLP 1.3.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ Battery Features: Charge Thresholds and Recalibrate
natacpi    = inactive (laptop not supported)
tpacpi-bat = inactive (laptop not supported)
tp-smapi   = inactive (laptop not supported)

+++ Battery Status: BAT0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = GLK MRD
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = Li-ion Battery
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    = (not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design             =  38000 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full                    =  50692 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now                     =  45121 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now                      =   3914 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Discharging

Charge                                                      =   89.0 [%]
Capacity                                                    =  133.4 [%]
```